# Non-zero exit status: "shinymanager" on Ubuntu EC2 AWS

Tags: r, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, shiny

I am trying to host a shiny app on an AW2 instance with ubuntu. This is the first time I have tried using an EC2 instance and the last package I need to install, "shinymanager" for the app is giving a non-zero exit status. Please let me know how to install "shinymanager" to the shiny-server on my ubuntu ec2 instance.

Ubuntu version: 18.04+

R version: `R version 4.1.2 (2021-11-01) -- "Bird Hippie"`

All the below packages have installed successfully through this method:

1. `/srv/shiny-server$ sudo R`
2. install.packages(c("package name"), dependencies = T)

Packages present in Global file that installed properly

```
library(tidyverse)
library(here)
library(janitor)
#library(lubridate)
#library(RPostgres)
#library(rstudioapi)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(DT)
#library(glue)
library(shinycssloaders)
#library(DBI)
library(gargle)
library(shinyalert)
library(googledrive)
library(shinylogs)
library(cachem)
library(shinymanager)
```

Here is the data and error I receive when trying `install.packages("shinymanager", dependencies = T)`

```
install.packages("shinymanager", dependencies = T)
Installing package into ‘/root/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
also installing the dependencies ‘sodium’, ‘RSQLite’, ‘keyring’

trying URL 'https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib/sodium_1.2.1.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 468055 bytes (457 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 457 KB

trying URL 'https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib/RSQLite_2.2.20.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 3745301 bytes (3.6 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 3.6 MB

trying URL 'https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib/keyring_1.3.1.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 45779 bytes (44 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 44 KB

trying URL 'https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib/shinymanager_1.0.410.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 2191864 bytes (2.1 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 2.1 MB

* installing *source* package ‘sodium’ ...
** package ‘sodium’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
Package libsodium was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libsodium.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'libsodium' found
Using PKG_CFLAGS=
Using PKG_LIBS=-lsodium
--------------------------- [ANTICONF] --------------------------------
Configuration failed because libsodium was not found. Try installing:
 * deb: libsodium-dev (Debian, Ubuntu, etc)
 * rpm: libsodium-devel (Fedora, EPEL)
 * csw: libsodium_dev (Solaris)
 * brew: libsodium (OSX)
If libsodium is already installed, check that 'pkg-config' is in your
PATH and PKG_CONFIG_PATH contains a libsodium.pc file. If pkg-config
is unavailable you can set INCLUDE_DIR and LIB_DIR manually via:
R CMD INSTALL --configure-vars='INCLUDE_DIR=... LIB_DIR=...'
-------------------------- [ERROR MESSAGE] ---------------------------
<stdin>:1:10: fatal error: sodium.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
--------------------------------------------------------------------
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘sodium’
* removing ‘/root/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/sodium’
* installing *source* package ‘RSQLite’ ...
** package ‘RSQLite’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** libs


###### Various Download info #########


The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/Rtmp9w5Zc6/downloaded_packages’
Warning messages:
1: In install.packages("shinymanager", dependencies = T) :
  installation of package ‘sodium’ had non-zero exit status
2: In install.packages("shinymanager", dependencies = T) :
  installation of package ‘keyring’ had non-zero exit status
```

### UPDATE

Inerestingly I was able to get `shinymanager` to download how ever I believe the LibPath is inccorrect. I believe I need to change it from `/root/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1` to `/usr/local/lib/R/site-library`

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wish I could give the exact solution but I am sure why it finally worked. I tried various `install.packages()` specifying libpath and dependencies. I then ran into the same issue with `RSQLite` and that worked eventually too after it failing for many tries and combinations.